# WMIC Output Result Without Property Name

Tags: cmd.exe, environment-variables, wmic

I'm entering this line:

```
wmic /OUTPUT:D:\DriverVersion.txt path win32_VideoController get driverversion
```

The txt file has two lines in it:

```
VariableValue
XX.XXX.XXX.XX.X
```

But I don't want `VariableValue` to get into output. I want simply get the output (`XX.XXX.XXX.XX.X`)

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the following:

```cmd
(@for /F "delims=" %I in ('wmic path Win32_VideoController get DriverVersion /VALUE') do @for /F "tokens=1* delims==" %J in ("%I") do @echo/%K) > "D:\DriverVersion.txt"
```

But this converts the Unicode output data to ASCII/ANSI.

If you want to use this code within a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file), ensure to double all `%`-signs.